# Плывет картинка bootstrap3

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Картинки не в ряд, почему так? Использовалась сетка  bootstrap3

```
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/1_top.png"></div>
    <div class="cod-md-6"><img src="img/2_top.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="img/ibert.png" />
        <img src="img/tigger.png" />

    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С размерами картинок все ок. Если давать в класс

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="img/ibert.png" />
    <img src="img/tigger.png" />

</div>
```

Вот так то картинка просто перемещается вправо, а вверх не ползет

```
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
        <img src="img/ibert.png" />
        <img src="img/tigger.png" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя для блока задан класс col-md-3, поэтому ширина блока не позволяет картинки в ряд разместить

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="img/ibert.png" />
        <img src="img/tigger.png" />
</div>
```

Поставь col-md-9, тогда они растянутся на ширину верхних двух картинок

Comment: вы не так поняли, нужно что бы они были справа вверху после центральной картинки, а не такой же шириной как те две картинки

Answer (score 0):

Решил, добавив во все классы pull-left

```
  <div class="col-md-3 pull-left"><img src="img/1_top.png"></div>
    <div class="cod-md-6 pull-left"><img src="img/2_top.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
        <img src="img/ibert.png" />
        <img src="img/tigger.png" />

    </div>
```